# How does one say "viewing party" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

I need a concise way to say "viewing party". It needs to be clear that it's about having a bunch of friends over to your house to watch a soccer game.
The phrase is:
"the elements of a perfect viewing party."

Comment: Good question. I am surprised that in Spanish we don't have an accurate word to say that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such translation for "viewing party" in spanish.

You must be more precise at what will you be watching. If it's a soccer game, then you can say:

> **"fiesta para ver el partido de fútbol"** - party to watch the soccer match

Comment: You're right, spanish doesn't have that expression. You must build one, another example will be: "tenemos todos los ingredientes para una perfecta noche de fútbol en mi casa" -> "we have all elements for a perfect soccer's night in my house"

Comment: "Noche de fútbol" es excelente... siempre y cuando el partido sea por la noche.

Answer (score -3):

Las claves para ver un partido de fútbol con los amigos.

Comment: This translation doesn't have any sense

Comment: I also don't think it has many sense, so I am downvoting it. However, it is still an answer, so it shouldn't be deleted. @prgrm: could you update it explaining why are you suggesting this and what sources helped you to think this is a valid translation?

Comment: From [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/209901) _For answers, any post that is [not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163730/when-should-i-delete-an-answer/163733#163733) (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted._